# SQL Server : get percentage of sales by country

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a T-SQL query that is calculating the sum of sales by country:

```
SELECT      
    SUM(F_Sales_Month.Sales_Qty), D_Customer.Country
FROM            
    F_Sales_Month
INNER JOIN 
    D_Customer ON F_Sales_Month.CustomerKey = D_Customer.CustomerKey
GROUP BY 
    D_Customer.Country
```

Result:

[image]

How can I get the percentage instead of the amount?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably the most efficient

```
declare @s money = (select sum(Sales_Qty) / 100.0 from F_Sales_Month);
SELECT      sum(F_Sales_Month.Sales_Qty) / @s as pct 
         ,  D_Customer.Country
FROM        F_Sales_Month
INNER JOIN D_Customer ON F_Sales_Month.CustomerKey = D_Customer.CustomerKey
GROUP BY D_Customer.Country

declare @t table (amt int, c char);
insert @t values 
(1, 'a'),
(3, 'a'),
(5, 'b'),
(11, 'c');
declare @s money = (select sum(amt) / 100.0 from @t)
select t.c, sum(t.amt) as sum, sum(t.amt)/@s as pct 
from @t t 
group by t.c
order by t.c;
```

Comment: you're missing the `* 100`

Comment: @SergioNeves If you are going to use that as the answer you can give it the check mark.

Answer (score 0):

I would use window functions:

```
SELECT c.Country  SUM(sm.Sales_Qty), 
       SUM(sm.Sales_Qty) * 1.0 / SUM(SUM(sm.Sales_Qty)) OVER () as country_ratio
FROM F_Sales_Month sm INNER JOIN
     D_Customer c
     ON sm.CustomerKey = c.CustomerKey
GROUP BY c.Country;
```

The `* 1.0` is because some databases do integer division.  If you really want a percentage between 0 and 100, then use `* 100.0`.

Comment: Thanks for the help but I get the following error: Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Column 'F_Sales_Month.Sales_Qty' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: @SergioNeves . . . Aggregations with window functions require two levels of `SUM()`s.  The fix is now in place.

Answer (score 0):

This should give your percentage

```
SELECT      sum(F_Sales_Month.Sales_Qty),
            sum(F_Sales_Month.Sales_Qty) / (SELECT sum(Sales_Qty)
                                            FROM F_Sales_Month
                                            INNER JOIN D_Customer ON
                                            F_Sales_Month.CustomerKey = D_Customer.CustomerKey) * 100.0
            as [PERCENT]
            D_Customer.Country
FROM            F_Sales_Month
INNER JOIN D_Customer ON F_Sales_Month.CustomerKey = D_Customer.CustomerKey
GROUP BY D_Customer.Country
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/a7e0f/3) with AdventureWorks2017-based example...

Comment: Not working. The column 'PERCENT' is coming out as 0.0 in every row